# Custom view for portrait and and orientation using storyboard using single view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, landscape, portrait

I have an app that requires me to have image views and labels to laid out differently depending on portrait or landscape orientation.

*For example*, in portrait mode, I have 2 UIImageViews on top and bottom that share the screen evenly. In landscape mode, the 2 UIImageViews are side by side. How can this be done using **storyboard in Xcode 6**?

Things I have tried:

1. Settings constraints on the views in storyboard with size classes. I
   set the base values for my 2 imageviews in `w:Any h:Any`, then moved
   to `w:Compact h:Regular` and set constraints for portrait view.Then
   I moved to `w:Any h:Compact`, moved the 2 imageviews side by side
   and set constraints for landscape view. Then *I get conflicts* in
   `w:Compact h:Compact` because of the constraints I have applied for
   and landscape and portrait orientation. I think it's because I moved
   the image views around for landscape orientation before settings the
   constraints that caused this problem.
2. Using 2 separate view controllers and have portrait view controller
   switch to landscape view controller when orientation changes using
   NSNotificationCenter and performSegueWithIdentifier to push the
   landscape view controller on top of my portrait view controller.
   This problem is that there's lots of data to be passed(lot of
   imageviews and labels).

Is the a way to use only one view controller and a way to rearrange the imageviews/labels and apply new constraints on them when the orientation changes? Is `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{}` where I put the code to rearrange the image views? Can someone point me in the right directions? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For this case I recommend to make layout programmatically via code.
Here is example:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/Test.zip

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self layoutImageViewsForViewSize:self.view.frame.size];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [self layoutImageViewsForViewSize:size];
}

- (void)layoutImageViewsForViewSize:(CGSize)size
{
    // Portrait mode
    if (size.height > size.width) {
        self.imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height / 2);
        self.imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, size.height / 2, size.width, size.height / 2);
        // Landscape mode
    } else {
        self.imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
        self.imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
    }
}
```

For autolayout:

```
- (void)layoutImageViewsForViewSize:(CGSize)size
{
    // Portrait mode
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    if (size.height > size.width) {
        NSString *heightLayoutFormatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[_imageView1(%.0f)][_imageView2(%.0f)]|", size.height / 2, size.height / 2];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:heightLayoutFormatString options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView1, _imageView2)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[_imageView1(%.0f)]|", size.width] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView1)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[_imageView2(%.0f)]|", size.width] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView2)]];

    // Landscape mode
    } else {
        NSString *widthLayoutFormatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[_imageView1(%.0f)][_imageView2(%.0f)]|", size.width / 2, size.width / 2];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:widthLayoutFormatString options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView1, _imageView2)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[_imageView1(%.0f)]|", size.height] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView1)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[_imageView2(%.0f)]|", size.height] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView2)]];
    }
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Another solution for autolayout - make your custom subclass of UIView, which contains 2 image views, and layout it programmly without constraints - just setFrame.
And then add this custom UIView to your storyboard

Comment: Is it possible to use storyboard with the above code instead of xib?

Comment: Yes, but there will be problem: you need disable autolayout. And it will be disabled for whole storyboard. Another solution - use storyboard and autolayout, but not change frame directly, only change constraints

Comment: If I use storyboard and autolayout, do I have to change the constraints programmatically? I tried moving the moving the imageviews in the view controller on storyboard(for side to side and top & bottom) and applying constraints on different size classes before and ended up with lots of conflicts. Is it possible to programmatically apply a set of constraints for landscape and portrait separately?

Comment: Updated answer for autolayout

Comment: I access my imageviews with self.imageView1 and self.imageView2 and got the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
self is not a key in the views dictionary. 
V:|[self.imageView1(334)][self.imageView2(334)]|

Comment: I got it working, but when I try to add button in the center of imageView1, I get an error saying unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-(%.0f)-[Button(75)]|", (size.width/2 - self.Button.frame.size.width/2)] options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(%.0f)-[Button(75)]|", (size.height/4 - self.Button.frame.size.height/2)] options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

Comment: your problem is that you need to make correct bind view variable to visual format. Here is simple example: constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|_button|": options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button)]

Comment: due to your crash report, I assume you have something like: constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|self.button|": options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.button)]